# Matrix brackets not scaling appropriately

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices

Part of the code from my uni thesis:

[tudelft-report.cls](https://pastebin.com/1tBQupJ1)

```
\documentclass[whitelogo]{tudelft-report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}  
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=cyan,bf}}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{comment}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[12pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan
}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\mathrm{R}_{z}}(\theta)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\label{eq:spin_z}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The Result:

[image: result]

What am I doing wrong? Is it a package issue? I also tried using an array with \left( and \right), but in vain.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please turn this into a Minimal Working Example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) by including the documentclass, one or two packages needed, and begin/end {document}.  Your example turns out just fine when I include what I guess to be the necessary items.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, I tried the same using the ```amsmath``` package as the only one and indeed: that looked like expected.

Comment: I'm actually using my university's latex template, so I guess including the .cls file here would not abide to the minimal working example requirement. Anyway, I'm pretty sure the error is in the class file now.

Comment: So it seems like you're using Overleaf. What compiler are you using and what version of TeX Live? Essentially we want to replicate your behaviour in order to provide a solution. And, *errors* essentially mean that you should disregard the output produced by TeX.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Overleaf indeed. Compiler: pdfLaTeX, TeX Live version: 2020

Comment: You can't use `lmodern` with that class. And if you are writing a thesis for that university you definitely shouldn't change their layout.

Comment: Nice, that was the problem indeed! Thank you!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved with the comments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error was a incompatibility with a custom class file.